# Gravitomagnetic Field vs Distance

Tags: general-relativity, dimensional-analysis, units, si-units, frame-dragging

If we look at what the Wikipedia says about gravitomagnetic fields $B$ generated by rotating planets / stars we have:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession#Gravitomagnetic_analysis

The problem is the resulting measurement units are: $$ m/s^2 $$ (gravitoelectric field).

Or:
$$
(kg*m*s^{-2}*m^2*kg^{-2})/(m/s*m^3)*(kg*m^2*s^{-1})
$$

So what is the correct scalar equation for the gravitomagnetic field $$ s^{-1} $$ of a rotating planet / star vs distance?

Comment: Why is this a problem?  The gravitoelectric acceleration around the Earth, for example, has a magnitude of $9.8 \text{ m/s}^2$, so the units are what we expect.  And the $\vec{B}$ field has the same units if you cancel thing out in your expression above.

Comment: The measurement unit of the gravitomagnetic field should be: $$ s^{-1} $$.

Comment: Not in the conventions used in the Wikipedia article you linked to above.  Lower down in that same article, the total force on a test particle is given as$$\vec{F} = m \left( \vec{E} + 4 \frac{\vec{v}}{c} \times \vec{B} \right)$$implying that $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ have the same units.  Other sources might use a convention where that factor of $c$ is folded into the definition of $\vec{B}$ instead, giving it units of $\text{s}^{-1}$ as you expect.

Comment: Yeah I suspected c might be in the way. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by Michael Seifert, you just have to divide by $c$.